# PHP DateTime first day of next year

Tags: php, parsing, datetime

I wonder if there is a 'correct' way to call:

```
$endDate = new DateTime('first day of next year');
```

I know the PHP parser expects a month after 
`of` ([see here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php#118062)), but `next year` seems to work sort of as intended. If the month is May, it will state April 1st of next year as `$endDate`.

Ofcourse we can hack around this with:

```
$endDate = new DateTime('first day of january');
$endDate->modify('+1 year');
```

But I can't imagine nobody would have fixed this 'bug' since PHP 5.3 came out 7 years ago.

Comment: Has this ever been flagged as a bug at bugs.php.net? If not, why should anybody have fixed it?

Comment: Just searched the bug tracking database a bit and there seem to be a few open issues about it, some even as old as 2010. It's how the DateTime parser works, but you'd think somebody would have fixed this by now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not quite as unambiguous as you might be looking for (are there any situations where January isn't the first month?), but this works fine back to PHP 5.2

```
$endDate = new DateTime('1st January Next Year');
echo $endDate->format('Y-m-d'); // 2017-01-01
```

https://3v4l.org/H5P8s

Comment: Omit "st" will give the same result: '1 January next year' or '1 Jan next year'. However 'January 1st Next Year' in the comment does not work for me.. Tested in PHP 5.2 and 5.6